# jquery .each() function issue objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I'm making an Carousel bootstrap menu.
Can anybody tell me, where my bug is?
This is JS code

```
        $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
      if (i == 0)
        $("<div>").addClass("item active").appendTo("#images");
      if ((i+1) % 3 == 0)
        $("<div>").addClass("item").appendTo("#images");

      $("<div>").attr("id", "image-" + i).addClass("col-sm-4 text-center").appendTo(".item");
      $("<a>").attr({
        "href" : "#",
        "class": "thumbnail",
        "id" : "thumb-" + i
      }).appendTo("#image-" + i);
      $( "<img>" ).attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#thumb-" + i);
      if ( i === 8 ) {
        return false;
      }
  });
```

HTML code

```
 <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
<div id="carousel">
    <div id="images" class="row">
    </div> 
</div>
<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
<!-- / -->
```

The output is like

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/21a051f608e89d8e89c85163de0ce1d7.png]

And I need just parse these object into dives.

Like first .item div includes image-0, image-1 and image-2 (and It's class is item active)
The next .item div includes image-3, image-4, image-5  (just parse objects in 3 in a row).

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this script wich create an item each three iterations an put subElement and image, like described in your post.

```
$.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
  // Create a div.item each 3 iterations
  if(i % 3 === 0) {
     $("#images").append('<div class="item"></div>');
  }

  // Get the last item and append images to it
  $("div.item").last().append('<div id="image-' + i + '" class="col-sm-4 text-center"></div>');

  // Append a href in element
  $("div#image-" + i).append('<a href="#" id="thumb-' + i + '" class="thumbnail"></a>');

  // Append image
  $("a#thumb-" + i).html('<img src="' + item.media.m + '"/>');
});

  // Then put the active class on the first item.
  $("div.item").first().addClass('active');
```

Comment: It's parsing array right but there are no images. Img wont append. I already fixed $("a#thumb-" +i)   (there wasnt that -  but It's still not working

Comment: I tested it in a JSBin and it works great. 

Run this code https://jsbin.com/rezipekoda/7/edit?html,js,output 

When you inspect the result, you can see the correct output.

Comment: Well I cant see the pictures. This is the HTML code after execution https://gyazo.com/d71c249ec3b8b82ca2a92bca51cf5a45

Comment: You're right, append method didn't work on a tags. You have to use html method. I've edited my code.

https://jsbin.com/vajorizake/1/edit?html,js,output